# Identify compatibility issues when migrating from SQL Server 2000 to 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-2000

We are planning to migrate from SQL Server 2000 to 2012. I understand this has  to be done this way.

> SQL Server 2000  ->  SQL Server 2005/2008  ->  SQL Server 2012

We first tested with SQL Server 2008 R2, but it has to be run under compatibility mode 80 due to some issues with some some stored procedures written using non-ANSI standard joins (eg. `*=` for `LEFT JOIN`). And I understand that SQL Server 2012 does not provide compatibility option for SQL Server 2000.

So I have to rewrite the stored procedures/views/functions in ANSI standard. But my question is how do I identify all the compatibility issues that would arise as a result of this migration? It is very difficult to go to each corner of the system and check. Are there any tools available to report the problem areas. or what is the best way to do this.

I have been searching for the past few hours and many people advice to test the system on SQL Server 2012 first. Yes i will do that but my worry is if something pops up later which we miss today. What is the expert way of doing this. Or should we settle with SQL Server 2008 R2.

Many thanks
John

Comment: There is no magic - you'll simply have to test it (and you *still* might miss stuff). Upgrade advisor & best practices analyzer can catch a lot, but not everything. And no, I wouldn't recommend sticking with 2008 R2 to avoid this work. (1) 2008 R2 is already out of mainstream support. (2) You can't stay on 2008 R2 forever either, so you're merely delaying the inevitable. See [this dba.se Q&A](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44908/what-is-the-actual-behavior-of-compatibility-level-80) and [this blog post](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-old-compatibility-levels/).

Comment: Also if you're considering 2012 but aren't committed to it, why not consider 2014?

Comment: 2012 is the latest accepted version in our org.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a similar migration: from SQL 2000 to SQL 2014.
Same problems.

There is just one solution I found: a bridge machine.

Step 1: collect a trace on SQL 2000. Template: SQLProfilerTSQL_Replay.

Step 2: run the advisor of SQL 2008 on the sql 2000 database, it also can process the trace.

Step 3: attach your databases on the sql 2008 bridge istance. Copy datafiles and attach them, use backup and restore, or what you prefer.

Step 4: raise compatibility mode to 2008 (or 2008r2, not a big difference).

Step 5: run the 2012 (2014 in my case) advisor.

Step 6: take the upgraded database on a sql 2012 istance and raise them to the new compatibility mode.

Step 7: run some check script.

```
DBCC CHECKDB WITH DATA_PURITY;
```

On all your databases.
Some racomand also:

```
DBCC UPDATEUSAGE(db_name);
```

Also I suggest to update stats and so on.
The problem will be more complicated if you have full text indexes and so on, but you have to face one problem ad the time.

Step 8: test all possible applications in a test environment.

Step 9: scare your boss. Next time you dont' need to jump 12 years of tech. I understand you, really, same problem.

Extra: write me if you want to exchange opinions and troubleshoting. I'm working on migration now.